# How to return subtype of a generic trait in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I am trying to create a factory pattern, and the return type is a parametrized trait, and the actual return type will be a subtype of that trait, but I do not know the generic type beforehand, so I don't know how to specify the return type. A simplified version is like this:

```
trait Mapper[T] {
    def createMap(a: T, b: T): T
}

class MapperA extends Mapper[String]{
    override def createMap(a: String, b: String): String = {
        a + b
    }
}

class MapperB extends Mapper[Int]{
    override def createMap(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
        a + b + b + b
    }
}

def factory(typeOfMapper: String): Mapper = {
    typeOfMapper match {
        case "mapperA" => new MapperA()
        case "mapperB" => new MapperB()
    }
}

val mapper = factory("mapperA")
```

This will give me and error of

> trait Mapper takes type parameters

but I do not know the generic type beforehand. What should the return type be for the `factory` method here?

Comment: Assume for a moment you are able to write that factory, how would the user of such `mapper` use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could return `Mapper[_]` ... that will compile, but isn't really very useful, as pointed out in the comments: you won't be able to use the returned value in any meaningful way, because actual type of `create` will be unknown.

If different instances of your mapper will always have different type parameters (at least, within the same scope), then a neat solution would be using implicits:

```
object Mapper { 
   implicit def strMapper: Mapper[String] = new MapperA
   implicit def intMapper: Mapper[Int] = new MapperB
}
```

Then everywhere you have these visible, you can just do:

```
      val m1: Mapper[String] = implicitly[Mapper[String]] 
      val m2: Mapper[Int] = implicitly[Mapper[Int]]
```

You could also write your factory function (though, I am not sure why you'd want to) like this:

```
    def mapperFactory[T: Mapper] = implicitly[Mapper[T]]
```

and use it like this:

```
     val m: Mapper[String] = mapperFactory
```

or like this

```
    def intMapper = mapperFactory[Int]
```

If you want different mappers for the same type parameter, it's basically the same idea, except it does't look as neat without implicits. The key is different factories for different types:

```
   class Mapper {
       def str(`type`: String): Mapper[String] = `type` match { 
         case "foo" => FooMapper()
         case "bar" => BarMapper()
       }
       def int(`type`: String): Mapper[Int] = `type` match {
          case "baz" => BazMapper()
          case "bak" => BakMapper()
       }
   }

   val fooMapper = Mapper.str("foo")
   val bakMapper = Mapper.int("bak")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in my case different mappers might have the same type parameter, they are differentiates by the typeOfMapper to decide which mapper to get

Comment: @I-PINGOu I added an explanation to the answer hoowo you can do that.